# Select most frequent value along with group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following SQL table

```
eventdate   userid  traffic location    
18.09.2023  user_1  10      A
18.09.2023  user_1  20      A
18.09.2023  user_2  10      B
18.09.2023  user_2  20      B
18.09.2023  user_2  30      B
18.09.2023  user_3  100     A
19.09.2023  user_1  50      B
19.09.2023  user_2  10      B
19.09.2023  user_2  20      B
19.09.2023  user_3  150     C
19.09.2023  user_3  250     C
20.09.2023  user_1  50      A
20.09.2023  user_1  20      A
20.09.2023  user_2  30      B
20.09.2023  user_3  110     C
20.09.2023  user_3  120     C
```

I want to have result as follows
eventdate - beginning of each week,
userid - unique user id per week,
traffic - sum of all traffics,
location - the most frequent location appeared with the week

For example

```
    eventdate   userid  traffic location
    18.09.2023  user_1  150    A
    18.09.2023  user_2  120    B
    18.09.2023  user_3  730    C
```

I was able to achieve the result with following query

```
SELECT t1.eventdate, t1.userid, t1.traffic, t2.location
  FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TO_DATE('2023-09-18', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'IW'),
                       'yyyy-mm-dd') AS eventdate,
               tk.userid,
               SUM(tk.traffic) AS traffic
          FROM test_kt tk
         GROUP BY tk.userid) t1
  JOIN (
         WITH cte AS 
        (
         SELECT tk2.userid,
                tk2.location,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                (PARTITION BY tk2.userid ORDER BY COUNT(tk2.location) DESC) rn
           FROM test_kt tk2
          GROUP BY tk2.userid, tk2.location
        )
        SELECT userid, location 
          FROM cte 
         WHERE rn = 1
       ) t2 
    ON t1.userid = t2.userid;
```

Are there any efficient ways to do so?

Comment: Please clarify your question and add some sample data and desired output in text format.

Comment: You write per week, but all your data are just within a few days. You could add some more data, to clarify. Week - is that Monday to Sunday (ISO weeks,) or something else?

Comment: Use [`STATS_MODE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/STATS_MODE.html#GUID-10BDACE0-C435-4E3F-BC50-FD1A41C0F508) function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may achieve the same with [`STATS_MODE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/STATS_MODE.html#GUID-10BDACE0-C435-4E3F-BC50-FD1A41C0F508) aggregate function:

```
with a(eventdate, userid, traffic, location) as (
  select to_date('18.09.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'user_1', 10,  'A' from dual union all
  select to_date('18.09.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'user_1', 20,  'A' from dual union all
  select to_date('18.09.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'user_2', 10,  'B' from dual union all
  select to_date('18.09.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'user_2', 20,  'B' from dual union all
  select to_date('18.09.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'user_2', 30,  'B' from dual union all
  select to_date('18.09.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'user_3', 100, 'A' from dual union all
  select to_date('19.09.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'user_1', 50,  'B' from dual union all
  select to_date('19.09.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'user_2', 10,  'B' from dual union all
  select to_date('19.09.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'user_2', 20,  'B' from dual union all
  select to_date('19.09.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'user_3', 150, 'C' from dual union all
  select to_date('19.09.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'user_3', 250, 'C' from dual union all
  select to_date('20.09.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'user_1', 50,  'A' from dual union all
  select to_date('20.09.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'user_1', 20,  'A' from dual union all
  select to_date('20.09.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'user_2', 30,  'B' from dual union all
  select to_date('20.09.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'user_3', 110, 'C' from dual union all
  select to_date('20.09.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'user_3', 120, 'C' from dual
)
select
  trunc(eventdate, 'iw') as eventdate,
  userid,
  sum(traffic) as traffic,
  stats_mode(location) as location
from a
group by
  trunc(eventdate, 'iw'),
  userid
```

| EVENTDATE | USERID | TRAFFIC | LOCATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-18 | user_1 | 150 | A |
| 2023-09-18 | user_2 | 120 | B |
| 2023-09-18 | user_3 | 730 | C |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OdD8ucTY)

**UPD**: You may also consult the documentation for this function that shows sample query to obtain multiple modes if they are exist (for which you will use `DENSE_RANK` in your original query in place of `ROW_NUMBER`).

Comment: I think this is perfect. Just wanted to write my answer with the identic query, but you were faster ;) Just to prove it's also working correctly with different weeks: https://dbfiddle.uk/QpEJgktU

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping, trying on my more complicated dataset.